# How to sort an array with PHP, ignoring the (Mr, Mrs) or Some articles

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Sort an array by using name 
I had an array.

```
 array(0 => Mr. Bala ,1 => Mr. Santhosh, 2 => Mrs. Camel,3 => Mrs. Vinoth);
```

Sort it in ascending order based on only Name

My expected output is

```
array(
  0 => Mr. Bala,
  1 => Mrs. Camel,
  2 => Mr. Santhosh,
  3 => Mr. Vinoth,
);
```

Comment: You want to use `usort`, where you define your own comparison function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just my own spin on it, should be a tiny bit more flexible. [Working Demo](https://ideone.com/zz4nYG)

```
usort($data, 'sortByName');

function sortByName($a, $b) {
    $remove = [' ', '.', 'Mrs', 'Miss', 'Ms', 'Master', 'Dr', 'Mr'];

    $a = str_replace($remove, '', $a);
    $b = str_replace($remove, '', $b);  

    return strcasecmp($a, $b);
}
```

Only caveat to be aware of is the `$titles` need to be in a certain order, as in `Mrs` must always come before `Mr` because `Mr` is within `Mrs` so if you switch the order then `Mr` may be taken away leaving a rogue `S`

Believe that should work for what you want, any issues let me know.

**Edit** Updated.

Comment: @KarthiM I believe that should work for you, if you get any further titles can just append onto the array.

Comment: @KarthiM Theresult is based on the name? Notice the names are in order `A > Avinshon > B > B > C > F > J` o.O

Comment: offcourse Priority 1 - Name remaining are the next priority

Comment: @KarthiM Not sure what you mean there.. the only reason it only shows letters is because that's the test data set I put in to make it easy to distinguish if it is in order. you can pass in any array of data to the `usort();` Working Demo is updated with your data set.

Answer (score 6):

using usort, taking 2nd part of string, splited by point with space after

```
usort($a, function($i1, $i2) {
        return strcmp(explode('. ',$i1)[1], explode('. ',$i2)[1]);
      });
```

**UPD** due to Bart Friederichs comment

```
usort($a, function($i1, $i2) {
            $t = explode('. ',$i1);
            $i1 = (! isset($t[1]) ? $i1 : $t[1]);
            $t = explode('. ',$i2);
            $i2 = (! isset($t[1]) ? $i2 : $t[1]);
            return strcmp($i1, $i2);
          });
```

[demo](https://eval.in/572580)

**UPD2** To make it case insensitive

```
usort($a, function($i1, $i2) {
            $t = explode('. ',$i1);
            $i1 = (! isset($t[1]) ? $i1 : $t[1]);
            $t = explode('. ',$i2);
            $i2 = (! isset($t[1]) ? $i2 : $t[1]);
            return strcmp(strtoupper($i1), strtoupper($i2));
          });
```

Comment: What if there is no `Mr.` or `Mrs.` ?

Comment: I've updated the answer by @BartFriederichs comment and added link to demo

Comment: @KarthiM Of course, any Uppercase letter <  any lowercase - https://eval.in/572590. Do you want case independent condition?

Comment: @splash58 It's working fine in name Scenario. If I had a full of letters without (.) It's your scenario might wrong. The scenario should satisfy any type of user input. https://eval.in/572605

Comment: I'm afraid that for universal solution will need much more code including support for language in which letters are written from right to left

Comment: I offered not only the algorithm but the working code. Hope OP can adapt it to his project details

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it, but with regex this time.
Also works if there is no "." after Mr or Mrs

```
$arrToSort = ["Mr. Bala","Mr. Santhosh","Camel","Mrs. Vinoth","Mr Roger","Mr. Calmator","Janette","Mrs Anne Couture"];
usort($arrToSort, 'ignore_Title');

function ignore_Title($a, $b){
    preg_match("/^Mrs{0,1}\.{0,1} (.*)$|/s",$a,$tmp);
    preg_match("/^Mrs{0,1}\.{0,1} (.*)$|/s",$b,$tmp2);
    return strcasecmp($tmp[1],($tmp2[1] == "" ?  $b : $tmp2[1]));
}
print_r($arrToSort);
```

Output :

```
[0] => Mr. Bala
[1] => Camel
[2] => Mr. Calmator
[3] => Janette
[4] => Mrs Lark Obm
[5] => Mr Roger
[6] => Mr. Santhosh
[7] => Mrs. Vinoth
```

Comment: `{0,1}` is equivalent to `?`